# How to force to create a company after first login with Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I'm building a SaaS with Symfony 2. Currently I'm adding registration of users to the application, but I don't know how to start.

I have no problems with basic user registration and login, my problem is another: When a user logs into the system, he **must** fill his company information. Even if the user goes to another URL, he must be redirected to the company information screen and he can't continue until he fills the company data. And the truth is that I have no idea of how to do this.

Can you help me, please? I know that I can add some checks to all of the controllers, but this is just an ugly hack...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the company information is important, add those fields to the register page. Don't create the account until all fields are filled.

Comment: This is not possible, because a user can have more than one company, and a company more than one user... But a user at least must have one company...

Comment: Well, the truth is that the only data I need from a new user's company is the name, so yes, I can add it at the register page and then create the company's entity... Very good point!

Answer (score 0):

Hard to answer without knowing anything about your application architecture. There's more than one way to do it.

One possible solution would be as long as the user did not fully fill out all the required information his account is *locked*, so whenever he tries to get onto another URL the access is denied (so essentially you've got three user states in your database or session storage or whatever) unless he enters his profile page and fills out all the requried information.

If he did so, his status changes to a "fully valid" user and he can login and browser the page however he likes.

So you don't have to check it on every page - just check if the user is logged in, locked or logged out.

If you have some kind of groups or roles in your application you could put your user into the "invalid" or "notcomplete" group which has basically no access to the application's pages.

Comment: Well, now I'm at a very early stage, so I haven't problems changing app's architecture. And I like the way you suggest, I'll study it deeply. Thank you!